# Android 11 restrictions on microphone use

Tags: android, android-service, android-permissions, background-service, android-11

Starting from Android 11, there are new restrictions introduced for microphone use. There are some exemptions given by Android. https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services#bg-access-restriction-exemptions. I'm interested in the last one -

```
The service is started by an app that has the START_ACTIVITIES_FROM_BACKGROUND privileged permission.
```

I declared this in the AndroidManifest.xml and allow-listed it, however, I'm still not able to use microphone when the app is running in background. Has anyone run into this before? Does the permission really help apps to escape from the restrictions? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`START_ACTIVITIES_FROM_BACKGROUND` is not part of the Android SDK. And its `protectionLevel` is set to `signature|privileged|vendorPrivileged|oem|verifier`, at least on Android 11. Ordinary apps cannot hold this permission.

Comment: Luckily the app I'm working on sits on system partition, and It also has some other privileged permissions like modifying system settings and displaying over other apps. To my understanding, It should be fine for us to grant START_ACTIVITIES_FROM_BACKGROUND, is that right?

Comment: @Sherly: "It also has some other privileged permissions like modifying system settings and displaying over other apps" -- `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` has `android:protectionLevel="signature|preinstalled|appop|pre23|development"` and `WRITE_SETTINGS` has `android:protectionLevel="signature|preinstalled|appop|pre23"`. So, unless your app is signed by the platform signing key, holding either of those other permissions does not mean that your app qualifies for `START_ACTIVITIES_FROM_BACKGROUND`.